# Sass parent selector interpolation

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to understand why interpolating the `&` in a sass selector is outputting the parent selector twice:

```
.a {
    &__element {
          #{ & }--modifier { // Why does this output .a__element .a__element--modifier ??
            color: blue;
          }
    }
}

.b {
    &__element {
          & &--modifier {
            color: blue;
          }
    }
}
```

[Compiles to](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3329af12af82118a415d1243983d5257):

```
.a__element .a__element--modifier {
  color: blue;
}

.b__element .b__element--modifier {
  color: blue;
}
```

I would expect it to simply output `.a__element--modifier`. Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the **&** in sass refer to the direct parent selector. when you add it to a sub selector the parent selector will not be accumulate in the output , unless you use the **#{}** syntax.

to get the expected output use:

```
.a {
    &__element {
        &--modifier {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So `&` is a special case that essentially removes the nesting. Using `#{ & }` appends the parent selector while also keeping the nested scope. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

```
.a {
    &__element {
          &--modifier {
            color: blue;
          }
    }
}
```

will compile to

```
.a__element--modifier {
  color: blue;
}
```

Interpolation simply inserts the value of `&` which is in our case `.a__element`, after which the selector is constructed.